# Why does vs2015 default nuget package include beta dependencies? And should I be installing them in my project?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, nuget-spec

When I create a new class library, for use with nuget, it has these dependencies / frameworks by default:

```
{
  //.... stuff.....

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
}
```

---

**Question 1**

Does `-beta-` in the dependencies section of project.json actually mean they're beta versions?!

If so, why is it creating dependencies on beta versions?

---

**Question 2**

When I install this nuget package, it attempts to install these dependencies alongside the package.

[image]

*But in the target application, do I not already have references to `System.Linq`, `System.Collections`, and so on?*

(I had wondered if this was because the nuget package was referencing the `-beta-` versions, rather than the `4.0.0.0` as referenced in the target project.  But this behaviour continued, event after changing `4.0.10-beta-23019` to `4.0.0.0` )

Comment: You're using `project.json`, which is part of the not-fully-released DNX etc ecosystem. Yes, everything's beta (or RC1) at the moment. If you create a "traditional" class library, you won't have a project.json at all.

Comment: Thank you Jon. So I should be going for `Class Library` project rather than `Class Library (Package)?` And would I then use the nuget package explorer to enter the details contained in `project.json`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's if you're happy *not* to target the new DNX stuff, of course.

Comment: TBH I'm not clued up enough to know what the implications would be. Right now I'd be happy to just to package up some MVC-age (models, enums, attributes) and have them as a shareable package.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Well I don't really know what you mean by "shareable package" at this stage, but that sounds like a different kind of question. I'd steer clear of DNX if you're not experienced in ASP.NET yet though - there are some rough edges still. I'm sure it'll be fine by release :)